# mySQL query statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have an error on $sql statement on output.

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"* This is referring to the UPDATE users SET activationkey statement.

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users"; 

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

if ($queryString == $row["activationkey"]){
 $sql="UPDATE users SET activationkey = '', status='activated' WHERE (id = $row[id])";

  if (!mysql_query($sql)) { *die('Error: in activation' . mysql_error());} 
}
 }
```

I don't know why that syntax is wrong.

Comment: Aside from your problem, you should be using mysqli or PDO. Check out http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers for PDO

Comment: UPDATE users SET activationkey = '', status='activated' WHERE (id = ) Oh, I am getting nothing from $row[id].

Comment: my mistake,  in my table, it's userid instead id.  $row[userid] now I am getting the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `activationkey` = '', status='activated' WHERE `id` = '$row['id']'";
```

Tip: I suggest securing your id because sql injection can be done in that query. By that I mean instant of saying WHERE `id` = '$row['id']', use WHERE `id`  = (int) ($row['id']),
This make sure only an integer is given in that query. If it was a string us mysql_real_escape_string($row['string'])